# how to change opacity of a div without changing opacity of other element in the same div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In my header div, I want to put opacity .75, however, I do not want to change the opacity of my logo which is placed in the div. Whenever, I put opacity to the whole div, it changes opacity of the logo as well. Can anyone help me in this regard?

Comment: Can you please provide us the current HTML and CSS? You may workaround that using the "RGBA" exploit, despite it is not supported in every browser.

Comment: Just change the opacity of what you want to fade, not the whole div

Comment: This is not possible, put the logo in an other container...

Comment: If your logo is a transparent png you can easily do this. I will see if I can make a fiddle.

Answer (score 7):

Try like this:

```
div{
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}
```

Comment: For fallback compatibility: https://css-tricks.com/rgba-browser-support/ despite only IE8 should not support that

Comment: I like to use a 1px semi transparent png as the fallback

Comment: @lharby: That's clever, indeed.

Answer (score 0):

You can give each div a class like so:

**HTML**

```
<div class="header">
    <div class="logo">Logo</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.header {
    width: 100%
    height: 500px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}
.logo {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
}
```

You can see an example, [here](https://jsfiddle.net/t25u5zrz/).

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to his here is another solution that will work with a transparent png logo

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/2/2d/SRU-Logo-Transparent.png" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    cursor:pointer;
    transition:all 400ms ease-in;
}

.wrapper:hover {
   background:powderBlue;
    transition:all 400ms ease-in;
}

.wrapper img {
    width:100%;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/lharby/zvb8868h/)

Or you can change the hover effect to rgba css

```
.wrapper:hover {
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}
```

Or use a 1px png

```
.wrapper:hover {
   background:url("/path/to/transparent.png") repeat;
}
```